# Group By SharePoint 2007 List

Tags: 2007, list-view, dropdown, grouping

I am using SharePoint 2007 and Share Point Designer.

Please help, if I have a List, how it it possible to group by on the aspx page?

For example I have a long list of dates:

12/1/2012

12/1/2012

12/1/2012

11/29/2012

11/28/2012

11/28/2012

I only need the followings to be show in a drop down filter:

12/1/2012

11/29/2012

11/28/2012

Is it possible in SharePoint 2007?

VB/JScript/... not allowed in the environment
I only can use xsl codes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about a View's aspx page or is this a custom ASPX page that you have created manually?

Comment: It should be grouped on a custom aspx page edited in SPD. The list is a standard custom list.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this meets your needs or not, but it is pretty standard OOTB:

1. Create a list.
2. Identify your group by field (StartDate).
3. Create a new view.
4. Scroll down to "Group By" section, and under, "first group by the column", select StartDate.
5. Ensure Collapsed is selected.
6. Click OK.

Your list now shows each unique StartDate in bold, which you can expand to show all items with that StartDate, just like Windows Explorer.

If you want to show your list on another page, just select your Group By view you created.